# WAV DATA как "сидят данные"

Tags: аудио, wav, форматы-файлов

Нашел много инфы про WAV формат , но про сами данные как они лежат не совсем понятно. Может кто из гуру подскажет. В частности есть хорошая статья http://www.frolov-lib.ru/books/bsp/v15/ch2_4.htm где вроде как и расписано в разделе "Формат файла WAV" что :

> Для монофонического сигнала с дискретностью 8 бит звуковые данные
>   представляют собой массив однобайтовых значений, каждое из которых
>   является выборкой сигнала. Для стереофонического сигнала с
>   дискретностью 8 бит звуковые данных имеют формат массива двухбайтовых
>   слов, причем младший байт слова соответствует левому каналу, а старший
>   - правому. Формат звуковых данных с дискретностью 16 бит выглядит аналогично. Для монофонического сигнала данные хранятся в массиве
>   16-битовых слов. Для стереофонического используется массив двойных
>   слов, причем младшему слову соответствует левый канал, а старшему -
>   правый. Диапазон изменения значений выборок сигнала определяется
>   дискретизацией. Для 8-битовых данных он составляет от 0 до 255 (0xff),
>   причем отсутствию сигнала (полной тишине) соответствует значение 128
>   (0x80). Для 16-битовых данных диапазон изменения составляет от -32768
>   (-0x8000) до 32767 (0x7fff), отсутствию сигнала соответствует значение
>   0.

Если прочитать из вырезки сказано что при дискретности 8 бит младший байт слова соответствует левому каналу, а старший - правому. НО ЕСЛИ мы возьмем из байта FF (8 бит) младший байт то там вместится только 15 максимально (F-15) откуда же там будет 128 ...128 будет если из FF (255) разделить на 2 но никак у них сказано что младший байт слова соответствует левому каналу....Такая же ситуация и с 16 битной дискретизацией...

Есть данные (WAV) моносигнал на 16 бит: Как они сидят в памяти (файле)...Из текст видно что сидят как

|два байта|два байта|два байта|

и опять таки диапазон значений от -32768 до 32768 ...Отсутствие сигнала 0 ? Если от 0 до 32767 меняется громкость то что тогда до -32767

Ну и такая же ерунда со стерео-данными на 16 бит....

Вообще интересно сделать элементарное увеличение/уменьшение громкости звука ...не используя bass ...по чистым данным wav файла....

Вроде как теоретически достатачно пройти по данным и их вытащить байт ,придавить например +1 и записать его назад...

Comment: Выходит, там знаковые числа: -128 для самого отрицательного напряжения на выходе, до 127 для самого положительного.

Comment: "... Младший байт слова ..." Слово - это 16 бит 88FF, Вот 88 это один канал, FF - другой. И да, данные представляют собой описание нестандартной синусоиды, громкость это не абсолютное значение байта, а амплитуда этой синусоиды.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/company/yandex/blog/270765/

Comment: Да Mike все верно ,если вот это значение : 55AC то 55 один канал ,а AC  другой канал ...В том то и дело ,что если так по словам раскидать то тогда мы не уложимся в диапазон ,который они указывают: "Для 16-битовых данных диапазон изменения составляет от -32768 (-0x8000) до 32767 (0x7fff), отсутствию сигнала соответствует значение 0."   ....В байте то 255 (FF) ,,,,

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/744941/wav-формат-Почему-размер-данных-не-кратен-размеру-сэмпла/804823#804823

Comment: @andrys201006 Вы путаете. 8бит не надо делить пополам. Если звук 8бит, то для стерео идет чередование, 8правый, 8левый.

Answer (score 2):

Данные WAV-файла, при использовании способа кодирования PCM или IEEE Float, располагаются в памяти как последовательность мгновенных значений звукового сигнала, считанных через равные промежутки времени (для каждого канала, если их несколько).

- Для 8-битных PCM данных, значения лежат в диапазоне от 0 до 255.
- Для 16-битных PCM данных, значения лежат в диапазоне от -32768 до 32767.
- Для 32-битных IEEE Float данных, значения могут быть любыми, но обычно они нормализованы в диапазон от -1.0 до 1.0

Отсутствие звука представляется не обязательно нулями, а любым постоянным значением (звук - это изменение сигнала, следовательно постоянный сигнал любой величины означает тишину). Графически звук можно представить как сумму синусоид, а тишину - как прямую линию, параллельную оси абсцисс.

Увеличение громкости звука нужно производить умножением семплов на какое-то значение, а не прибавлением, так как громкость - это амплитуда колебаний (синусоиду надо "растянуть" вдоль оси ординат, а не просто параллельно сдвинуть вверх). Для этого проще всего преобразовать значения в тип float и все промежуточные операции делать с ним, чтобы избежать переполнения. Если после умножения значение выходит за рамки допустимого диапазона, его нужно обрезать (таким образом, чем больше увеличение громкости, тем больше потери информации).

Пример кода на C# для работы с 8/16 битными PCM или 32 битными IEEE Float данными:

*Вспомогательные классы*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace WaveRead
{   
    /// <summary>
    /// Класс, осуществляющий чтение/запись RIFF WAV файлов
    /// </summary>
    public class WavFile
    {
        public string FilePath { get; set; }

        public WavFile(string file)
        {
            FilePath = file;
        }

        public WavData ReadData()
        {
            var header = new WavHeader();
            byte[] data;
            using (var fs = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (var reader = new BinaryReader(fs))
                {
                    //считываем заголовок
                    header.ChunkId = reader.ReadInt32();
                    header.ChunkSize = reader.ReadInt32();
                    header.Format = reader.ReadInt32();
                    header.Subchunk1Id = reader.ReadInt32();
                    header.Subchunk1Size = reader.ReadInt32();
                    header.AudioFormat = reader.ReadInt16();
                    header.NumChannels = reader.ReadInt16();
                    header.SampleRate = reader.ReadInt32();
                    header.ByteRate = reader.ReadInt32();
                    header.BlockAlign = reader.ReadInt16();
                    header.BitsPerSample = reader.ReadInt16();

                    if (header.Subchunk1Size == 18)
                    {                        
                        header.FmtExtraSize = reader.ReadInt16();
                        reader.ReadBytes(header.FmtExtraSize);
                    }

                    //пытаемся считать данные
                    header.Subchunk2Id = reader.ReadInt32();
                    header.Subchunk2Size = reader.ReadInt32();

                    while (true)
                    {
                        data = reader.ReadBytes(header.Subchunk2Size);
                        if (header.Subchunk2Id == 0x61746164) { break; }//данные найдены

                        //если Subchunk2Id нет тот, что ожидался, пропускаем и пробуем снова
                        header.Subchunk2Id = reader.ReadInt32();
                        header.Subchunk2Size = reader.ReadInt32();
                    }    
                }
            }

            var result = new WavData(header, data);           

            return result;
        }

        public void WriteData(WavData input)
        {
            var header = input.Header;
            byte[] data = input.Data;
            using (var fs = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(fs))
                {
                    //пишем заголовок
                    writer.Write((int)header.ChunkId);
                    writer.Write((int) header.ChunkSize);
                    writer.Write((int) header.Format);
                    writer.Write((int) header.Subchunk1Id);
                    writer.Write((int) header.Subchunk1Size);
                    writer.Write((short) header.AudioFormat);
                    writer.Write((short) header.NumChannels );
                    writer.Write((int) header.SampleRate);
                    writer.Write((int)  header.ByteRate);
                    writer.Write((short) header.BlockAlign);
                    writer.Write((short) header.BitsPerSample);                    

                    if (header.Subchunk1Size == 18)
                    {
                        writer.Write((short) 0);    
                    }

                    //пишем данные
                    writer.Write((int) header.Subchunk2Id);
                    writer.Write((int)header.Subchunk2Size);
                    writer.Write(data);

                }
            }            
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Представляет звуковые данные в формате PCM или IEEE Float
    /// Позволяет осуществлять чтение/запись семплов для форматов 8/16 бит PCM и 32 бит IEEE Float
    /// </summary>
    public class WavData : IDisposable
    {
        public WavHeader Header {get;set;}
        public byte[] Data { get; set; }
        BinaryReader _read;
        BinaryWriter _write;

        /// <summary>
        /// Создает экземпляр WavData с указанным заголовком и пустым массивом данных указанного размера
        /// </summary>        
        public WavData(WavHeader hdr, int size)
        {
            Header = hdr;
            Data = new byte[size];
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Data);
            _read = new BinaryReader(ms);
            _write = new BinaryWriter(ms);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Создает экземпляр WavData с указанным заголовком и массивом данных
        /// </summary>
        public WavData(WavHeader hdr, byte[] d)
        {
            Header = hdr; Data = d;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Data);
            _read = new BinaryReader(ms);
            _write = new BinaryWriter(ms);

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Возвращает число семплов в массиве данных
        /// </summary>        
        public int GetSamplesCount()
        {
            return Data.Length / ((int)Header.BitsPerSample / 8);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Читает следующий семпл в виде float-значения. Целочисленные данные нормализуются в диапазон от -1 до 1
        /// </summary>        
        public float ReadNextSample()
        {
            float res = 0.0f;

            switch (Header.AudioFormat)
            {
                case 1://PCM
                    if (Header.BitsPerSample == 8)
                    {                        
                        res = (_read.ReadByte() - 128.0f) / 255.0f;
                    }
                    else if (Header.BitsPerSample == 16)
                    {
                        res = (_read.ReadInt16()) / 32767.0f;
                    }
                    else throw new ApplicationException("BitsPerSample value not supported");
                    if (res > 1.0f) res = 1.0f;
                    if (res < -1.0f) res = -1.0f;
                    break;

                case 3: //IEEE Float
                    if (Header.BitsPerSample != 32) throw new ApplicationException("BitsPerSample value not supported");
                    res = _read.ReadSingle();
                    break;
                default: throw new ApplicationException("AudioFormat value not supported");
            }

            return res;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Записывает значение следующего семпла. Для PCM значение должно быть нормализовано в диапазон от -1 до 1
        /// </summary>        
        public void WriteSample(float val)
        {
            switch (Header.AudioFormat)
            {
                case 1://PCM
                    if (Header.BitsPerSample == 8)
                    {
                        _write.Write((byte)((val + 2.0f)*128.0f));                        
                    }
                    else if (Header.BitsPerSample == 16)
                    {
                        _write.Write((short)(val * 32767.0f)); 
                    }
                    else throw new ApplicationException("BitsPerSample value not supported");                    
                    break;

                case 3://IEEE Float
                    if (Header.BitsPerSample != 32) throw new ApplicationException("BitsPerSample value not supported");
                    _write.Write(val); 
                    break;
                default: throw new ApplicationException("AudioFormat value not supported");
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _read.Dispose();
            _write.Dispose();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Представляет заголовок RIFF WAV файла
    /// </summary>
    public struct WavHeader
    {        
        public int ChunkId { get; set; }
        public int ChunkSize { get; set; }
        public int Format { get; set; } //"WAVE"
        public int Subchunk1Id { get; set; }//"fmt "
        public int Subchunk1Size { get; set; }
        public short AudioFormat { get; set; }
        public short NumChannels { get; set; }
        public int SampleRate { get; set; }
        public int ByteRate { get; set; }
        public short BlockAlign { get; set; }
        public short BitsPerSample { get; set; }
        public int FmtExtraSize { get; set; }

        public int Subchunk2Id { get; set; } //"data" (0x61746164)
        public int Subchunk2Size { get; set; }// numSamples * numChannels * bitsPerSample/8   
    }

}
```

*Пример использования (увеличение или уменьшение громкости на заданный коэффициент)*

```
WavFile file = new WavFile(tbInputFile.Text); //входной файл
WavData orig = file.ReadData();
WavData processed = new WavData(orig.Header, orig.Data.Length);

using(processed)
using (orig)
{
    int c=orig.GetSamplesCount();

    float x;
    float y;
    int clipped = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        x = orig.ReadNextSample(); //читаем следующий семпл                    

        y = x * (float)numericUpDown1.Value; //умножаем значение на коэффициент

        //если значение выходит за рамки поддерживаемого диапазона, обрезаем
        if (y > 1.0f) { y = 1.0f; clipped++; }
        if (y < -1.0f) { y = -1.0f; clipped++; }

        processed.WriteSample(y); //записываем полученный семпл
    }

    WavFile new_file = new WavFile(tbOutputFile.Text); //выходной файл
    new_file.WriteData(processed);

    MessageBox.Show("Файл обработан! Потери данных: "+
        ((clipped * 100.0f) / (float)c).ToString("F2")+" %");

}
```

Подробную информацию о формате WAV-файлов можно найти здесь: http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html