# Как преобразовать WAV файл в стандарт PCM?

Tags: python, аудио, wav

Как преобразовать файл формата `.wav` в файл `.wav` стандарта `PCM` c помощью [python](/questions/tagged/python).

Answer (score 2):

Насколько понял под PCM вы понимаете сырые данные т.е. последовательность байт где каждый (для примера 16-битный) сэмпл закодирован 2-х байтным signed-16-bit-integer. Сэмплы конечно могут быть и 8 битные, я просто упомянул 16-битные.

Если PCM это нечто другое чем сырые байты сэмплов, то мой ответ будет полезным просто для тех кому нужны сырые сэмплы.

Такие данные из WAV можно получить например двумя путями, один из них более надёжный, используя библиотеку [pydub](https://pypi.org/project/pydub/) (установить через `pip install pydub`).

Второй более топорный, без библиотек, но может НЕ ВСЕГДА работать, лучше его не использовать. Несжатые WAV файлы часто имеют заголовок ровно 44 байт, но не всегда, затем до конца идут чистые данные, в итоге если начиная с этого смещения до конца файл прочитать то будут сырые PCM данные.

Сырые PCM данные будут в том формате в котором они были внутри WAV закодированы, т.е. столько же бит, такой же порядок байт и такая же знаковость.

Оба метода приведены ниже, возвращают байты сырых данных в `data` и `data2` переменных.

**Внимание!** Используйте только первый `pydub`-основанный метод, второй метод только для примера приведён и будет не всегда работать (если заголовок WAV не 44 байт).

[Попробовать код онлайн!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/RuStackOverflow1268137#main.py)

```
import pydub
with open('sound.wav', 'rb') as f:
    data = pydub.AudioSegment(f).export(format = 'raw').read()
with open('sound.wav', 'rb') as f:
    f.seek(44)
    data2 = f.read()
assert data == data2
```

---

Если нужно сконвертировать формат из одного вида в другой, например из сжатого WAV в несжатый то делаем следующее, здесь `format = 'wav'` может быть заменён на любой формат, скажем `'mp3'` или `'flac'`:

```
import pydub
with open('sound.wav', 'rb') as f, open('sound_out.wav', 'wb') as fo:
    fo.write(pydub.AudioSegment(f).export(format = 'wav').read())
```

Comment: PCM может быть не только 16-битным, но и 8-битным. И предположение, что в WAV данные идут после фиксированного смещения в 172 байт в общем случае некорректно, так как после заголовка могут быть быть другие блоки, например INFO. На эту проблему уже натыкались: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/804823/240512 Лучше использовать библиотеки, либо реализовать корректный пропуск неизвестных блоков RIFF.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Спасибо за информацию. На самом деле 16-битный я упомянул просто для примера, мол о чём идёт речь говоря про PCM, я не говорил что он только 16-битный бывает. Также по поводу заголовка 172 байт, именно для этого я написал что первый метод через `pydub` библиотеку надёжный, использовать его надо, а второй через 172 байт не всегда работает и его лучше не использовать. Я только что обновил ответ написав большими буквами НЕ ВСЕГДА работает.

Comment: Сделал все как написано к сожалению не сработало, ошибка: "pydub.exceptions.CouldntDecodeError: Couldn't find fmt header in wav data", прогуглил решения так и не нашел.

Comment: @Максим А входной файл точно в WAV формате? Может у него просто расширение wav а на самом деле другой формат? Попробуйте вместо `pydub.AudioSegment(f)` использовать `pydub.AudioSegment.from_wav('filename.wav')`. Также ещё попробуйте конвертировать используя [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html), например так `ffmpeg -i input.wav -c copy output.wav`. О результатах сообщите в дальнейшем комментарии.

Comment: @Arty Заменил `pydub.AudioSegment(f)` вышло это: "invalid start code OggS in RIFF header, harvard.wav: Invalid data found when processing input". при использовании `ffmpeg -i input.wav -c copy output.wav` вот это: "Codec opus not supported in WAVE format. Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Function not implemented. Error initializing output stream 0:0 --"

Comment: @Максим Попробуйте тогда открыть как OGG файл, т.е. `pydub.AudioSegment.from_ogg('filename.wav')`, похоже какой то странный нестандартный способ кодирования - внутри WAV инкапсулирован кодек OGG. Видимо редкие конверторы смогут это поддержать. Если не получится, попробуйте открыть файл через плэйер [foobar2000](https://www.foobar2000.org/download), если получится и он проигрывается то дальше внутри интерфейса foobar2000 правой кнопкой на открытом трэке жмём и там будет в меню Convert, в котором выбираем Output Format равный WAV и дальше конвертируем.